# Html.Action() extension method encoding the = sign in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, extension-methods

I have a action in controller which is returning the View return type is ActionResult and in View Im calling it using Html.Action() method all is going perfectly but when page is loaded it change the query string means encode the query string like = sign with %3F but not all of = signs

How can I get rid of these encoding ???

here is code:
Controller

```
 public ActionResult FetchCartItemsByOrderId(int OrderId)
    {
        CartViewModel cart = new CartViewModel();

        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            cart.order = db.Orders.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == OrderId);
             cart.listOrderDetail = db.OrderDetails.Where(x => x.OrderId == OrderId).ToList();
        }


        return View("~/Views/Generic/_ViewCart.cshtml", cart);

    }
```

View:

```
@Html.Action("FetchCartItemsByOrderId", "Generic", new { orderId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["orderId"]) });
```

[image]

Comment: Are you facing a problem because of the encoding ?

Comment: Yes, it encode the accessToken url parameter

Comment: It is encoding just the accessToken because it is (probably) base64 encoded and normally ends with =. If you try to prevent it from getting encoded you may have problems with the URL parser.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira yes you got it but I want to use it with base64 encoding how can I overcome with parser issues is there any way ?

Comment: Where are you having problems with the base64 encoded value? Because MVC normally handles the URL encoding itself.

Comment: Not only the access token is getting encoded but also the ? in the returnUrl parameter which is correct as there cannot be more than one in an url. It seems to me that MVC is encoding the url to save it for a later redirect in a similar manner to the way login works in a default MVC project. Is this your situation?

Comment: @Beorn yes its the situation

Comment: Then it seems to be working as intended. It's encoding the returnUrl parameter so it can be later used to do a server side redirect (which will unencode it automatically).  Can you better detail what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Beorn thanks buddy i got it u'r right it is just because of ? replication in url .. thumbs up